# Installing apk files in BeagleBoard having gingerboard

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

I wish to install a apk file in beagle board having gingerbread Android. Unable to access files which are in my sdk card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install the files by writing on the SD card it won't work, you have to install them.

The official solution to do so is to call (from the shell)

```
   adb install [-r] yourPackage.apk
```

(the -r is optional and may be necessary from time to time)

On the beagleboard you usually run a android that is rooted with write-access to system, so installing shouldn't be a problem.

If the adb can't find a device please read the official documentation. You may have to add the usb-vendor id to adb.ini/android.ini and modify udev-rules on linux systems. But all this is documented in the 'android for beagleboard' release you've got.